# Chrome web driver and selenium tests version problem

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

In my project where I write web automation tests using Selenium web driver, I am experiencing version problems after every new Chrome update. Chrome updates happen very frequently and I get this error again and again due to version incompatibility almost periodically. I think Chrome updates the driver of the current browser later and my tests are not running during this time.

The error message I received is;

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 122.0.6261.57 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

Do you have any permanent solution suggestions for this problem?

I turned off Chrome updates, I expect this to be a solution in the future. However, since I cannot find the appropriate version of Maven plugins at the moment, my tests are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use WebdriverManager you should update the version to the latest (5.6.4)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also make sure to clear the local cache:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
```

Comment: The main reason for the error was that the driverCache was not cleared. Your answer was helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your selenium library version to 4. Now selenium will automatically take care of using Chrome Driver based on browser version.

Maven dependency for the Latest version is:

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.18.1</version>
</dependency>`
```